# In nixos, how to remap caps lock to control?

Tags: nixos

I followed the instructions at [this email thread](https://mailman.science.uu.nl/pipermail/nix-dev/2017-January/022443.html), and placed

```
services.xserver.xkbOptions = "grp:alt_space_toggle, ctrl:swapcaps";
```

in my `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix` file, but even after rebuilding with `$ nixos-rebuild switch`, and rebooting with `nixos-rebuild boot` and `reboot`, my caps lock key is not remapped.

**How to map caps-lock to ctrl in nixos?**

Comment: `services.xserver.xkbOptions` should work, I am currently using this to set my caps <-> esc with `caps:swapescape`. maybe it is a bug.

Comment: Note that option is only for the Xserver (Xorg). Did you test it within X windows?

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa sorry but I am not clear on the difference. How can I know whether my window is in X window or Xorg?

Comment: If you have a GUI, your in Xorg. Does the mapping work in say... your web browser?

Comment: @EmmanualRosa yes I have a GUI using gnome. The mapping does not work in my web browser.

Comment: @mherzl Is this only a problem in your web browser, or does this affect all graphical programs?

Comment: @gmarmstrong I have the same problem. I'm new to NixOS. I stuck `services.xserver.xkbOptions = "ctrl:swapcaps";` into my configuration.nix, and after a reboot and back into Gnome Desktop (on X11, not Wayland), capslock is still capslock and ctrl is still ctrl. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 8):

As you already tried, and [as grwlf suggests](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/528691/191530), you can enable this **in X11** by adding `services.xserver.xkbOptions = "ctrl:swapcaps";` to `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix`.

To apply this setting in **outside of X11**, you can add `console.useXkbConfig = true;` to the configuration. This will apply the X keymap to the console keymap, which affects virtual consoles such as `tty`.

**UPDATE:** `i18n.consoleUseXkbConfig` [was renamed](https://nixos.org/manual/nixos/stable/release-notes.html#sec-release-20.03-incompatibilities) to `console.useXkbConfig` in NixOS version 20.03

Comment: I tried option but it doesn't work, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Works for me (after a reboot).

Comment: Does not work for me, even after reboot on `20.09.3436.6be212cce73 (Nightingale)`.

Comment: Works for me (after a reboot), on NixOS 21.11.

Answer (score 6):

Let's say you have a `configuration.nix` like this.

```
  services.xserver.enable = true;
  services.xserver.layout = "pl";
  services.xserver.xkbOptions = "ctrl:nocaps";
  services.xserver.displayManager.gdm.enable = true;
  services.xserver.displayManager.gdm.wayland = false; # or true
```

Build it normally with `nixos-rebuild switch`.

Then run these commands:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources
```

Now reboot.

Looks like the gsettings options are built once and don't pick up the changes to your `configuration.nix`. The commands above should reset the settings causing the values from `configuration.nix` to be picked up.

Source: https://discourse.nixos.org/t/problem-with-xkboptions-it-doesnt-seem-to-take-effect/5269/2?u=yeewe4

Comment: This worked for me, thank you so much ! Note that after those 2 commands, my keyboard reverted to qwerty which made the `sudo reboot` awkward. After reboot all is fine.

Answer (score 4):

In my `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix` config,

```
  services.xserver = {
    ...
    xkbOptions = "ctrl:swapcaps";
    ...
  };
```

`ctrl:swapcaps` option swaps Capslock and Control.

Comment: I stuck `services.xserver.xkbOptions = "ctrl:swapcaps";` into my configuration.nix, and after a reboot and signin to Gnome Desktop (on X11, not Wayland), capslock is still capslock and ctrl is still ctrl.

Comment: Did you run `nixos-rebuild switch` or analog to apply the configuration? In NixOS editing the config is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

By default, `ctrl:swapcaps` only swaps <kbd>Left Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>, which is perhaps is not what you need.

A dirty solution is

```
services.xserver.xkbDir = "/usr/share/X11/xkb"
```

then

```
mkdir -p /usr/share/X11 && cp /run/current-system/sw/share/X11/xkb /usr/share/X11
```

and edit it to reach your perpose. Note, you need backup `/usr/share/X11/xkb` by yourself!